# Do I actually need google-play-services_lib in project to use google cloud messaging?

Tags: android

Can I only use Google Cloud Messaging in  my app while having its google-play-services_lib  in the project? or are there other ways

Answer (score 0):

> Do I actually need google-play-services_lib in project to use google cloud messaging?

Yup, Google play services library is required for GCM and should be installed in your device also, alternative is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In a new approach you need a google-play-services to use cloud messaging service.

I think, there is one more concept is present that using of [gcm.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmjar.htm) file.(But this concept was Deprecated one.)